# SQL sum a particular row based on condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using `MS SQL Server`. This is the table I have:

```
Create table tblVal
(
Id int identity(1,1),
Val NVARCHAR(100),
startdate datetime,
enddate datetime
)
--Inserting Records--
Insert into tblVal values(500,'20180907','20191212')
Insert into tblVal values(720,'20190407','20191212')
Insert into tblVal values(539,'20190708','20201212')
Insert into tblVal values(341,'20190221','20190712')
```

**Table as this:**

```
   Id   |Val        |startdate      |enddate
   --- ----------------------------------------------
    1   |500        |2018-09-07     |2019-12-12 
    2   |720        |2019-04-07     |2019-12-12 
    3   |539        |2019-07-08     |2020-12-12 
    4   |341        |2019-02-21     |2019-07-12
```

**This is what I want:**

```
Mon     |   Total
------------------
Jan     |   500
Feb     |   841
March   |   841
April   |   1561 
May     |   1561
June    |   1561
July    |   2100
........|.........
```

I want to sum `Val` column if it lies in that particular month. For ex. in case of `April` month it lies between two of the rows. I have to check both the condition start date and end date. and then sum the values.

**This is what I have tried:**

```
select *
into #ControlTable 
from dbo.tblVal

DECLARE @cnt INT = 0;
while @cnt<12
begin
select sum(CASE  
             WHEN MONTH(startdate) BETWEEN @cnt and MONTH(enddate) THEN 0 
              ELSE 0 
           END) 
 from #ControlTable
SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;
end

drop table #ControlTable
```

but from above I was unable to achieve the result.
How do I solve this? Thanks.

Comment: Was going to type up solution but I believe you need to take Year into account as well unless you want to sum up counts from April 2018 and April 2017 (for example) in your total?  You can do a SUM on month, Group By Year, Month

Comment: @Brad Yes I need year as well.It would be much better then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you want something like this:

```
with dates as (
      select min(datefromparts(year(startdate), month(startdate), 1)) as dte,
             max(datefromparts(year(enddate), month(enddate), 1)) as enddte
      from tblVal
      union all
      select dateadd(month, 1, dte), enddte
      from dates
      where dte < enddte
     )
select d.dte, sum(val)
from dates d left join
     tblval t
     on t.startdate <= eomonth(dte) and
        t.enddate >= dte
group by d.dte
order by d.dte;
```

This does the calculation for all months in the data.

The results are a bit different from your sample results, but seem more consistent with the data provided.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=229ad5b5176d35dba70cf7613e10ece6) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Hi if i understand your wall query i think this query can respond :

```
Create table #tblVal
(
Id int identity(1,1),
Val NVARCHAR(100),
startdate datetime,
enddate datetime
)
--Inserting Records--
Insert into #tblVal values(500,'20180907','20191212')
Insert into #tblVal values(720,'20190407','20191212')
Insert into #tblVal values(539,'20190708','20201212')
Insert into #tblVal values(341,'20190221','20190712')

Create table #tblMonth ( iMonth int)
Insert into #tblMonth values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12);


select * from #tblVal
select * from #tblMonth

SELECT *, SUM(case when Val is null then 0 else cast (Val as int) end) OVER(ORDER BY iMonth
     ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as 'Totaltime'
FROM #tblMonth 
LEFT JOIN #tblVal ON MONTH(startdate) = iMonth
ORDER BY iMonth

drop table #tblVal
drop table #tblMonth
```

Not you have to use SQL Server version 2008 min  for use OVER(ORDER BY iMonth
     ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)

Link :

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

If you have older version you can use CTE or JOIN ON select .

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @outpuTable Table(
MOn INT,
Total nvarchar(MAX)
)

DECLARE @cnt INT = 1;
while (@cnt<=12)
begin

INSERT INTo @outpuTable VALUES(@cnt,
(select ISNULL(sum(CONVERT(INT,Val)),0)
 from tblVal
WHERE  @cnt BETWEEN MONTH(startdate) and MONTH(enddate) ))

SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;
end

Select * from @outpuTable
```